# replace 'hi' with 'bye' in a string but exclude hit in java but exclude 'hit'

Tags: java, string

like `String str="ahibhitc";` as input and the output is like 1 telling number of time hi appears in the string , abhitc removing hi from the string but excluding hit as it is and  finally abyebhitc replacing all  hi with bye but excluding  all hit keyword in the string. i tried im able to count the no of times hi appears but cant replace hi with bye as hit also gets replaced. all i know string are immutable so stored the result in new string .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in); 
     String str="ahibhitc";
    // str=scn.nextLine();
     StringBuilder str1= new StringBuilder(str);
     //System.out.println(str1);

     int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i)=='h'){
            if(str.charAt(i+1)=='i'&& str.charAt(i+2)!='t')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i)=='h'){
            if(str.charAt(i+1)=='i'&& str.charAt(i+2)!='t')
            {
                str1.delete(i, i+2);
                //str1.replace(i, i+2, "");

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str1);
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i)=='h'){
            if(str.charAt(i+1)=='i'&& str.charAt(i+2)!='t')
            {

                str1.replace(i, i+2, "bye");

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str1);
  }
}
```

Comment: also it works only if hi comes 1st

Comment: what about words like `hid` ?

Comment: only it hit then it should not be replaced by hi else every where it should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="ahibhitc";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("hi(?!t)", "bye")); // Negative lookahead for "t" after "hi"
}
```

O/P :

```
abyebhitc
```

use `?i` qualifier to make the regex case insensitive.

Comment: In my opinion we should not just provide solution to OP but also guide so that next time he/she can do by himself/herself. OP's post shows that he's beginner to Java and SO as well but telling him to use Regex is not doing any good for him. Instead of correcting logic he'll start learning Regex. That's definitely wrong direction.

Comment: @Azodious - Why would learning regex be wrong?. They are incredibly helpful. IMO I am helping the OP solve this problem without *reinventing the wheel* :). Also, I usually expect people to show their effort. That is why I waited for the OP to show what he / she has tried before posting this answer

Comment: Regex is not an easy concept. It's a language in itself with short grammar rules. You are definitely helping him but just in this problem. if he gets similar problem, say replace all 'hit' except 2nd occurrence, he can't do it. I think regex should be used only if you are clear with logic that how to do without using regex.

Comment: @Azodious - IMO the OP will have to learn it *one day* :). Also, one `replaceAll` is faster than 2 `replace` calls.. Having said that, I think its best to end that conversation :)

Comment: Yes, He will have to learn it one day but why to make java look harder than it is, and that too for beginner. Well, i guess, he got what he wants. but that level SO has already reached. Lets move one step ahead. :) together.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this done would be first, replacing all string instances of "hit" with some placeholder string(say "%")(Make sure that this does not appear in the input string as @GhostCat said). Then after this, replace all "hi" string with "bye". Then replace the placeholder string("%") with "hit".

Example:

```
   String str="ahibhitc";
   String intermediateString = str.replace("hit","%");
   String result = intermediateString.replace("hi","bye").replace("%","hit");
   System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Where you have to check **first** if that replacement patterns is **not** present in the input string.

Comment: A negative lookahead is perhaps the best solution here

Comment: yeah thank for your answers , tried both the above solutions  seems easy to understand the concepts .  also im new to java as well so take a bit time for to visualize things...